# How to map array of object dynamically

Tags: javascript

```
var data = [

    { extn: '2014', agentid: 'sravya', comments: '' },

    { extn: '2015', agentid: 'shalini', comments: '' }

    ]

 const localityParameterSets = data.map(function(value){

       return [

            {name:"extn",value:{stringValue:value['extn']}},

            {name:"agentid",value:{stringValue:value['agentid']}},

            {name:"comments",value:{stringValue:value['comments']}}

            ]

    })

    console.log(JSON.stringify(localityParameterSets))
```

The above code is working fine but I need to make this name and value  dynamically without hardcode i.e key value
for example "extn" string is hardcoded instead key value should come
"agentid" string is hardcoded instead key value should come

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? A simple `for...in` would be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Object.entries and build the object dynamically.

```js
var data = [

  {
    extn: '2014',
    agentid: 'sravya',
    comments: ''
  },

  {
    extn: '2015',
    agentid: 'shalini',
    comments: ''
  }

]

const localityParameterSets = data.map(function(value) {

  return Object.entries(value).map( ([key,val]) => ({name:key, value:{stringValue:val}})) 
  
})

console.log(localityParameterSets)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the entries and map objects.

```js
const
    data = [{ extn: '2014', agentid: 'sravya', comments: '' }, { extn: '2015', agentid: 'shalini', comments: '' }],
    result = data.map(o => Object.entries(o).map(([name, value]) => ({ name, value })));

console.log(result);
```